# Uniq and counts

Tags: linux, shell, count, uniq

Have a file with 2 columns,
need to use uniq on column 1 only and print 
both the columns in the results as well as the count of the occurrences 
(with -c).

Example:

```
1 a
1 a
2 a
3 c
4 d

2 1 a
1 2 a
1 3 c
1 4 d
```

Comment: if you needed to compare on column 2 only, you would just need this option


-f, --skip-fields=N
              avoid comparing the first N fields

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '1 a
1 a
2 a
3 c
4 d
' | uniq -c
```

outputs exactly your 2nd block.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you mean by "use uniq on column 1 only." What do you want to happen if column 1 appears multiple times with different column 2 values? If this can happen, your question probably needs a little clarification. If this can't happen in your scenario, then the easiest solution is probably

```
uniq -c filename
```

Answer (score 0):

if this in a file then

```
cat filename.txt|awk '{print $1}'|uniq -c
```